# Impersonation using absolute path

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a file using impersonation. Everything works fine when the file folder is shared. However when the folder is not shared and try to access the file using absolute path, it does not work.

It works:  \\folder\test.txt

It does not work:  \\nt9999\d$\folder\test.txt

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like a permissions/ share issue / rights are you sure that you have access to the \\nt9999\d$ share..? also are you certain that the machine that you are trying to get to has a d: drive.. who's your system / network administrator..??

Comment: I give the user full control of the folder. Once I share the folder then I can access it using \\sharefolder\test.txt, but when I unshare and try to access the file using absolute path then I get "The network path was not found".

Comment: This isn't an issue of absolute path vs. a share.  As I point out in my answer below, *both* of these approaches use shares, and (as @DJKRAZE points out) both shares are subject to share permissions and shares being enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `D$` share is called an [Administrative share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share), and may be disabled, or the user that you are impersonating may not have access to it.

What error do you get?

Comment: I tried other drives also. Same error "The network path was not found".

Comment: If it doesn't work in Windows explorer, then why would it work in C#?  You'd need to get your network admin to open the share.

Comment: Please let me know what I need to do for it. I am new to this.

Comment: Assuming this is Windows 7, http://chall32.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-enable-access-windows-7.html